# Javascript: How to get the value of class set in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a complete novice with javascript, so understand this is simple for most, but how to I obtain the value of an class item which has been set in a javascript array.

I need to check value of "page" and if = value do something, output rendered html code

```
<script>
  function subst() {
  var vars={};
  var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
  for (var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
  var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
  for (var i in x) {
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
    for (var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: "how to I obtain the value of an class item which has been set in a javascript array" - this is not clear. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, can you please try to clarify what the expected result is?

Comment: I think they just simply want to retrieve the class name for an element. document.getElementById('page').className